# C# csExWB and cookie

Tags: c#, cookies

I am trying to download daily a content of a webpage using csEXWB for my c# application usage. The site requires authentication for this. Using my browser and fiddler i got the cookie which contains my authentication information.

I have 2 questions:
1.How can i send a download request using this cookie to the webpage?
2.Can I prevent my cookie from expiration?

I am really new to cookie usage. Any pointer would be helpful.

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that creates an HTTP request with a session cookie:

```
private HttpWebRequest CreateRequest(string url, string method, string sessionCookie)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
    throw new ArgumentException("Empty value", "url");
  HttpWebRequest result = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
  if (result == null)
    throw new ArgumentException("Only the HTTP protocol is supported", "url");
  result.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
  if (sessionCookie != null) {
    result.CookieContainer.Add(
      new Uri(url), 
      new Cookie(SessionCookieName, sessionCookie)
    );
  }
  result.Method = method;
  return result;
} // CreateRequest
```

where 'SessionCookieName' is the name of the cookie to send.

The cookie expiration is controlled by the originating Web site, you cannot prevent it from expiring.

I think that what you should really do is to write code that does the log-in to the Web site - how to do it would depend on how the login works on the Web site you want to access.